# Проблема с ScrollBar и OnTouchListener у TextView

Tags: android, ontouchlistener

Проблема заключается в том, что на моей Activity есть TextView и для него включен ScrollBar. Но так же для моей Activity есть обработчик OnTouchListener и они не могут работать вместе. Когда я устанавливаю обработчик нажатия для всего Layout, то он не работает, работает лишь ScrollBar. А если устанавливаю обработчик для TextView, то наоборот, не работает ScrollBar. Как можно решить эту проблему?

Вот код обработчика :

```
 public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
    Display display = ((WindowManager) getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE)).getDefaultDisplay();
    Point p = new Point();
    display.getSize(p);
    int width = p.x;
    float x = event.getX();
    float widthOfOnePart = width/3;

    switch (event.getAction()){

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            if (x < widthOfOnePart)
                Toast.makeText(this, "Переход на предидущую страницу", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            if (x >= widthOfOnePart & x < widthOfOnePart * 2) {
                Animation transDown = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.trnslatedown);
                Animation transUp = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.translateup);

                if (topBar.getVisibility() == View.INVISIBLE) {
                    topBar.setAnimation(transDown);
                    topBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    bottomBar.show();
                }
                else {
                    topBar.setAnimation(transUp);
                    topBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                    bottomBar.dismiss();
                }
            }

            if (x >= widthOfOnePart * 2)
                Toast.makeText(this, "Переход на слеующую страницу", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            break;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Метод onCreate(); :

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_reader);

    cl = (CoordinatorLayout) this.findViewById(R.id.activity_reader);
    cl.setOnTouchListener(this);

    topBar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.reader_activity_toolbar);
    topBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

    text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvMainText);
    text.setMovementMethod(new ScrollingMovementMethod());
```

}

Comment: Когда вы возвращаете true, это значит, что вы обработали нажатие и больше передавать никому ничего не нужно. Попробуйте возвращать return false;

Comment: Проблема исправилась, но не до конца. Теперь они работают вместе. Сначала OnTouchListener, а потом скролл. Мне же нужно чтобы они срабатывали в зависимости от ситуации. Т.е. при нажатии без скролла OnTouchListner, а при скролле наоборот.